# How can I interrupt a delay() when a button is pressed?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, code-review

I have created a device that allows my son to track time spent on activities and exchanges that time into a time he can use with his electronics (eTime).

[Full code in GITHUB](https://github.com/islandwonderer/eTimeBank)

I am having trouble coding the part of the code that handles the countdown from his earned eTime. As it is right now it can count down and give him a warning when his eTime has run out, but the process can't be interrupted.

I would like to have him be able to stop his eTime and use the remainder later. I tried putting the function in a while loop.

```
while(digitalRead(button_9)==LOW){
    delay(60000);
    avail_time -= 1;
    if(avail_time<0){
      playAlarm();
      return;
}
```

This one registers the keypress but ignores the delay.

I have also tried using a for loop to count down and another to check every second for a keypress.

```
void useTime() {
  for(int i=avail_time+1; i>0; i--){
    displayTime(i);
    for(int minute=60; minute>0; minute--){
      if(digitalRead(button_9)==HIGH){
        avail_time = i;
        return;
      }
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  while(digitalRead(button_9)==LOW){
    tone(buzzer, 2000);
    }
  noTone(buzzer);
  avail_time=0;
  displayOptions();
  return;
 }
```

That one does not register the keypress.

Comment: look at the `blink without delay` example sketch

Comment: Use timestamp instead of delay(), see [Blink Without Delay](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-led-blink-without-delay) example

Comment: I took a look to your code in Github. I think you also need to [debounce for button](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button-debounce)

Comment: You asked "How can I interrupt a delay() when a button is pressed?" The short answer is that you can't. `delay()` is a blocking function. It can't be interrupted. You need to refactor your code as others have suggested.

Comment: You can if you handle your button press in a pin change interrupt handler. But still it is bad practice to use delay(). The only legit use is a timed sequence where you are not doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function to check the current 'time'. If you store this, and later call this function again, by subtracting you can see how much time has been passed. so instead of `delay(500)` you use `if (millis() - timeStamp >= 500) { ...` to continue your code.

As others said in comments,  you also need to debounce to prevent multiple button triggers.

**Edit: Debouncing**

There is not a library for debouncing (at least not one on the Arduino site), but you can easily copy the needed code from the following sketch:

[Arduino Debounce](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce)

Comment: I was able to use this solution. I have not implemented debounce yet but I'm looking into it. Is there a debounce library or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your question in the comment.